# .nextUntil to from at th through specified th

Tags: jquery

I'm using jQuery to hide table rows up until today's date and this works:

```
$('.date_display').each(function(i, cell){
    if (cell.scope == 'header') {
        if ($(cell).text() == today){
                return false;
            }
        }
        $(cell).parent().hide();
    });
```

But I can't seem to get `nextUntil` working (jQuery v 1.11.1):

```
var showMe = $("th.mz_date_display:contains('"+today+"')");
$('th.date_display').first().nextUntil(showMe, 'tr').hide();
```

`showMe` is returning an object in the console.

MWE of HTML:

```
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th class="date_display">Monday</th>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td class="date_display">some text</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td class="date_display">some text</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <th class="date_display">Tuesday</th>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td class="date_display">some text</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td class="date_display">some text</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <th class="date_display">Wednesday</th>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td class="date_display">some text</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td class="date_display">some text</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

1. [Fiddle of non-nextUntil way](http://jsfiddle.net/mikeill/58cpt90f/1).
2. [Attempt with nextUntil](https://jsfiddle.net/mikeill/czxbynnb/2/).

Comment: Would you be able to create a demo fiddle so we can see your complete javascript, html, css, etc?

Comment: Post your HTML in your question.

Comment: here's a fiddle of the way I'm currently doing it: https://jsfiddle.net/mikeill/58cpt90f/1/

Comment: This is the attempt using `nextUntil`: https://jsfiddle.net/mikeill/czxbynnb/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is in the way you used `nextUntil`. It only returns the siblings of the `selector`. In your code, `$('th.date_display')` refers to the siblings of the `th` element while each `th` does not have any siblings in its `tr`. To fix this, you need to search among `tr` elements, not the `th` element:

```
(function($){
   $(document).ready(function($) {
      var showMe = $("th.date_display:contains('Wednesday')").closest("tr");

      $('th.date_display').closest("table").find("tr:first").nextUntil(showMe, 'tr').addBack().hide();

   }); // On doc ready

})(jQuery);
```

Check out the working example in [**JSFIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/unhkhpj0/1/)